# Git commits to show live on website

Tags: html, git

So I have a bitbucket repository I push my code to. How can I hook up my repository and have it so that anything that gets committed shows on my site?

Comment: How are you hosting your site?

Comment: Set up post-commit hooks.

Comment: @raina77ow - I'm guessing you meant "post-commit"

Comment: "Post"-commit hooks? :)

Comment: For reference, [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) is the Git documentation page on post commit hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this link https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Bitbucket+hooks you can find a documentation on how to add a hook. Add a POST hook to call a url on your server. This url should point to a script (PHP for example) to git pull, check this blog post http://jondavidjohn.com/git-pull-from-a-php-script-not-so-simple.